# Search Azure DevOps git repository via REST API

Tags: git, azure-devops-rest-api

Using the Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient I can connect to a Azure DevOps project and get a git client e.g.

```
   var connection = new VssConnection("https://dev.azure.com/myorg", new VssBasicCredentials(string.Empty, "patToken"));
   var client = await connection.GetClientAsync<GitHttpClient>().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I can see methods to get items from the repository, what I can't see are any search methods as github provides - do they exist?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Code Search APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/search/code%20search%20results/fetch%20code%20search%20results?view=vsts-rest-4.1), not the Git APIs. The Git APIs are more focused on providing methods for interacting with Git repos, as opposed to searching for items within a Git repo.

Comment: Are the code search APIs part of the client library or do I have just call the REST API directly?